# Some CSS or JS issue with Social Media Widget

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am facing an issue with social media widget (sidebar) as its working fine on the post page but on homepage it not working.

Please check the demo

Post Page: www.goo.gl/BJOJ34

Home Page: www.goo.gl/p42S9F

for more info please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: what you have tried so far?add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing CSS so write css on your index or Post page and check. below CSS works for facebook button. Copy CSS from your `these-10-startups-won-singapore-central.html` page and paste on `index.html` or `post page`.

```
.smart-connect .follow_blog .btn_fb
{
    background: #3a579a;
}

.smart-connect .follow_blog ul li
{
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 3px 5px 0;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 165px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all .4s;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro for help